# Does Fire Shield count as a shield that gives an AC bonus?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, shield

While the level 4 fire shield spell is out and equipped, does it count as a shield and give the shield AC bonus? It isn’t specified in the description of the spell, so I’m just curious.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Fire Shield does not give an AC bonus.

As you say, the description of the spell does not specify that it is a shield that gives an AC bonus. Because [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), no more and no less, the spell does not give an AC bonus.

Additionally, the description of the spell states that it's more of a body-surrounding aura than a sturdy, holdable shield:

> Thin and wispy flames wreathe your body for the duration...

Answer (score 5):

As Icyfire said, spells do only what they say they do. But more to the point of order: Many spells have Misleading Titles, and for decades, several spells were printed that began with disclaimers "this spell doesn't actually___ but".

For example Summon Wind Dragons from Al Qadim begins: "Despite its name, this spell does not summon any sort of creature".

The "Shield" aspect of the spell is metaphorical, in that it protects the caster, providing *resistance* to your choice of fire or cold.